# OnLoad is not firing when page opens from a HREF or BACK

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a page(index.html) which has header/body defined as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<body class='theme-light' data-background='none' data-highlight='red2' onLoad='loadAppMenu()'>
    <div id="footer-bar" class="footer-bar-1">

    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function loadAppMenu(curPage) 
{
     $("#footer-bar").empty();
     var iHTML = (curPage=='index.html'?'<a href="#" class="active-nav"':'<a href="index.html"') + "><i class='fa fa-home'></i><span>Home</span></a>" + 
                 (curPage=='favourites.html'?'<a href="#" class="active-nav"':'<a href="favourites.html"') + "'><i class='fa fa-star'></i><span>Favourites</span></a>" + 
                 (curPage=='search.html'?'<a href="#" class="active-nav"':'<a href="search.html"') + "'><i class='fa fa-search'></i><span>Search</span></a>" + 
                 (curPage=='Profile.html'?'<a href="#" class="active-nav"':'<a href="Profile.html"') + "'><i class='fa fa-user'></i><span>Profile</span></a>" + 
                 "<a href='#' data-menu='menu-settings'><i class='fa fa-cog'></i><span>Settings</span></a>";
    $("#footer-bar").html(iHTML);
}
</script>
```

Everything works fine. Now I navigate out to another page. Where I have link like below:

```
<a href="index.html" class="active-nav"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span>Home</span></a>
```

Now when I click Home, it loads the page but the onload function is not getting executed! Same behaviour when I click the BACK button on the browser.

I know there is fundamentally simple that Iam missing here. Please help its driving me nuts!!

1. Yes I have the .js file referred properly in the end
2. Yes there is a function loadAppMenu, because the menu gets loaded to a div when I hit REFRESH page
3. Im using jQuery v3.3.1 js file.

Comment: Updated my question.